# API responding with Malformed JSON string

Tags: c#, json

I am trying to post data to an API but I am getting an error saying, "Malformed JSON string". I constructed my object based on the payload which I was given, which has been tested from python and is working fine.

What is it that am doing wrong based on my code below?

**Original JSON payload which I have been given and I need to build from it**.

```
{'i_customer': 1, 'custom_fields_values': [{'i_custom_field': 1, 'db_value': '2'}]}
```

**My code attempt:**

```
CustomField custom = new CustomField()
{
    CustomerId = customerId,
    CustomFieldsValues = new CustomFieldsValues()
    {
        CustomFieldId = _portaClient._CustomFieldId,
        DbValue = customFieldId
    }
};

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(custom);
string url = string.Format(endpoint);
var client = new RestClient(url)
{
    Timeout = -1
};

var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.AddParameter("params", "{\"information\":" + json +  "\"}");
--              
var response = client.Execute(request);
```

**The above code produces this payload:**

```
{"i_customer":1,"custom_fields_values":{"i_custom_field":1,"db_value":"2"}}
```

API error response:

> **Error**: "
> {"faultcode":"malformed_json_string","faultstring":"Malformed JSON string"}"

**This is my model**

```
public class CustomField
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "i_customer")]
    public int? CustomerId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "custom_fields_values")]
    public CustomFieldsValues CustomFieldsValues { get; set; }
}

public class UpdateCustomerCustomFieldsValuesResponse
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "i_customer")]
    public int? CustomerId { get; set; }
}

public class CustomFieldsValues
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "i_custom_field")]
    public int CustomFieldId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "db_value")]
    public string DbValue { get; set; }
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Apostrophes are not valid around JSON property names. They need to be quotes. That "Original JSON" is invalid. If the service is expecting apostrophes, it's broken. *Horribly, stupidly broken.*

Comment: It's probably expecting `custom_fields_values` to be an array and not an object.

Comment: @James i have changed it but not to sure how i can re-map this code? 

CustomField custom = new CustomField()
{
    CustomerId = customerId,
    CustomFieldsValues = new CustomFieldsValues()
    {
        CustomFieldId = _portaClient._CustomFieldId,
        DbValue = customFieldId
    }
};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FWIW, I believe the error is not accurate. "Malformed" has a very specific meaning that does not apply here, in that your result is well-formed and valid JSON data. This valid JSON result isn't structured in a way their system would like, which is still an error... just not the same kind of error as sending "malformed" JSON.

To fix this things, this `CustomField` class:

```
public class CustomField
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "i_customer")]
    public int? CustomerId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "custom_fields_values")]
    public CustomFieldsValues CustomFieldsValues { get; set; }
}
```

needs the `CustomFieldsValues` property to show as an array or list:

```
public class CustomField
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "i_customer")]
    public int? CustomerId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "custom_fields_values")]
    public List<CustomFieldsValues> CustomFieldsValues { get; set; }
}
```

And then, of course, you must also update any code which populates this object accordingly:

```
CustomField custom = new CustomField() { 
    CustomerId = customerId, 
    CustomFieldsValues = new List<CustomFieldsValues> { 
        new CustomFieldsValues() {
           CustomFieldId = _portaClient._CustomFieldId, 
           DbValue = customFieldId 
        } 
    }
};
```

Finally, if they really do want single-quotes for field names, they've got a lot of nerve telling you your JSON is malformed, when in fact it is their own system using malformed and non-standard JSON.

Comment: How do i then change the mapping before posting to the API?

CustomField custom = new CustomField()
{
    CustomerId = customerId,
    CustomFieldsValues = new CustomFieldsValues()
    {
        CustomFieldId = _portaClient._CustomFieldId,
        DbValue = customFieldId
    }
};

Comment: It seems to be rejecting the correct JSON format and looking for single quotes. How can i send it in single quotes? Is that even possible?

Comment: @Ribon That would be **VERY** strange. Given they won't give you more specific errors, I'd make sure this is really what's happening. Have you tried POSTing raw string variable with various JSON samples to confirm this?

Comment: The error that i am getting is Malformed JSON string. I tried to put raw string like the below The API response became 200 but not updating the fields from the API.

request.AddParameter("params", "{\"customer_info\":" + json + ", \"i_customer\":\"" + customerId + "\"}");